# Python Pyglet mouse event handling

Tags: python-2.7, mouse, pyglet

My code goes like this:

```
@window.event()

def on_mouse_press(e, d, button, modifiers):

    y=400
    for i in temp2:
        if button == mouse.LEFT:
            pyglet.text.Label(i, font_name='Arial', font_size=24, x=50, y=y,
                                    batch=batch)
            y += -30
            break
```

What I want to do here, is that everytime left mouse button is cliked, the element in the array will show in the window. However, the code print it all at once. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe is not really reproducible. If anything, merely the very first item in your array `temp2` is being displayed in the `Label` you create, since you iterate through the array and spawn labels without any condition on the item's position. Then, you break immediately after the first item has been represented by a label. Is this what you are trying to accomplish? Also, the condition `button == mouse.LEFT` doesn't really change during the iteration on the array, so the nesting of the `if`-statement and the loop might as well be reversed.

Regarding the decorator `window.event`: Its implementation catches the way you are using it, but it is not really the way it is meant to be used. Instead, you should either use it without parenthesis (just `@window.event`) or specify the nature of the event to be handled as a string parameter (`@window.event('on_mouse_press')`), in case the function name differs from the event name.

Again, I am pretty sure the code you posted will not display the entire array `temp2`, but only the first element. For a more helpful answer, you should elaborate the nature and contents of the array and the way an element is supposed to be chosen for display.